# Unable to add tags to Compute Engine instance as Project Owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-compute-engine

I am using Google Cloud and I have created a compute instance for which I am trying to add a tag. Unfortunately, even though I am the project Owner, I can't seem to add a tag because I am "missing" this permission.

[image]

Although, if I check the roles that have this permission, I get the following:

[image]

I have added myself as Editor and Tag User, but still get the same permission error.

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error message, you need to have a permission   `resourcemanager.tagValueBindings.create`

Please note that you must have an organization resource to use tags. For more information about acquiring an organization resource, see [Creating and managing organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization#acquiring). You may refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-creating-and-managing) for more information about creating and managing tags.

Then you can add the "[Tag User](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resourcemanager.tagUser)" role at organization level.